# How to count the combnation which consists of two values both from different tables?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have the next schema:
[the schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1W6i.png)

I need to identify those car owners who are always serviced by the same mechanic and output the names of the mechanic and his regular customer.

I have tried this code, but it only gives me the combinations, how can I count this combinations and print the most frequent?

```
select cars_license_plate,mechanics_personnel_number,count(*) from orders where cars_license_plate in
    (
        select license_plate from cars where drivers_license_number in
        (
            select license_number from drivers where full_name in(select distinct full_name from drivers)
        )
    ) group by cars_license_plate, mechanics_personnel_number
;
```

Comment: You must join all tables (except workshop), group by car owner, and compare distinct mechanic amount with 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)